# How to have Php Code Sniffer run all PSR2 sniffs except one

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a php library I'm writing. It uses Doctrine. Php code sniffer with `standard=PSR2` passes on my code with the exception of where I use constants defined in the Doctrine. Many Doctrine constants are not all uppercase, as PSR2 requires, but I can't change them because they are not defined in my library. How do I get Code Sniffer to check my library, but ignore those constants defined in Doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `@codingStandardsIgnoreStart` and `@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd` annotations. Eg:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

See the section 'Ignoring Parts of a File' in http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.advanced-usage.php